# mysql --> yearly max value with infomation of record id

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the yearly max values and the record id information for further joins with other tables.

Consider the following table:

```
tur_id  Datum   SZ  Art VW  StV TV  NSP
189 23.06.2010  09:40:00    S   1   -37 -35 46
7   11.05.2012  08:40:00    S   1   -19,9   -21 45
140 02.07.2011  10:30:00    S   1   -25 -26 45
62  31.07.2013  31.07.2013  S   1   -16 -16 42
136 12.07.2011  11:20:00    S   1   -21,4   -23 41
181 04.08.2010  10:00:00    S   1   -30,1   -28 41
195 24.10.2009  09:40:00    S   1   -45 -47 41
90  22.10.2013  22.10.2013  S   1   -14,2   -16 40
11  16.06.2012  10:50:00    S   1   -17 -18 40
153 13.05.2011  09:25:00    S   1   -27,4   -29 40
1   23.07.2014  23.07.2014  S   1   -13,6   -14 39
56  15.06.2013  15.06.2013  S   1   -17,3   -18 39
45  26.10.2012  26.10.2012  S   1   -17,4   -18 39
.....
```

The following query returns the yearly max values without record id (in my case turid).

SELECT year(datum) rok, max(nsp) FROM `turniere` GROUP BY year(datum)

Result:

```
rok max(nsp)
2009    41
2010    46
2011    45
2012    45
2013    42
2014    39
```

How can I get the info of the turid or the datum value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are half-way there.  Join the original data back in:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM turniere t JOIN
     (SELECT year(datum) as rok, max(nsp) as maxnsp
      FROM turniere
      GROUP BY year(datum)
     ) tt
     ON year(t.datum) = tt.rok and t.nsp = tt.maxnsp;
```